# Limiting Visual Studio nuget from suggesting incompatible packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Now, that .net 8 is out, and many-many packages have their updated version also out, it is really annoying that VS is suggesting updates that are not compatible with the project target framework. I have to stick .net 7, but get all those package update suggestions that all have .net 8 as dependency. I there any way to specify a filter at project level?

[image: screenshot for clarification]
(note: prerelease checkbox makes no difference here)

Comment: Do you mean the intellisence of the Visual Studio, if so, the answer should be no, because there are not too many settings about intellisence, it just recommand the latest version of the package.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT No, not intellisense, the "Manage Nuget packages" tool. It fetches the metadata for the package that contains the dependency and directly works with the project file itself, hence I see no obstacle in doing the filtering.